# AWS Athena JDBC Driver ResultSet.getCharacterStream method not implemented

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have an Athena/PrestoDB query that returns up to 300 million device ids.  This screen shot shows the query when executed in the AWS UI.  The results were displayed in under 1 minute and I downloaded the full results (319MB) in a few minutes from the link provided in the UI.

[image]

When I execute the same query over the JDBC connection I'm receiving a method not implemented error.  It appears the AthenaJDBC41-1.0.0.jar from the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) has not implemented the **getCharacterStream** yet.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: ActiveRecord::JDBCError: com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.NotImplementedException: Method ResultSet.getCharacterStream is not yet implemented: SELECT distinct(device_id) FROM presales.sightings_v3 WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN DATE('2016-03-01') AND DATE('2016-03-02') AND ( contains(audiences, 1133) OR contains(audiences, 1149) OR contains(audiences, 1184) );
```

I'm using driver AthenaJDBC41-1.0.0.jar from the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) and my [example connection can be seen here](https://github.com/jspooner/athena-jruby-connection-example).

My guess is that the method **ResultSet.getCharacterStream** is only used with large results since my other queries work fine.

Ideally I would like this response to contain the query_id or S3 Path vs streaming the big data results.  I'm curious how the Athena UI generates a link to the results on S3?

Comment: Rahul Pathak also said ResultSet.getCharacterStream will be implemented in the next version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the query id from the ResultSet

```
((AthenaStatementClient)((AthenaResultSet)rs).getClient()).getQueryExecutionId()
```

With that you can build the S3 Path with

```
<s3_staging_dir>/<query_id>.csv
```